# When to use watchQuery or query in Apollo-Angular?

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am using a  watchQuery or query in Apollo-Angular (graphql)

How is the logic and difference of the watchQuery and query

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`query` is something you just query for once, you can consider it as an equivalent of GET.

`watchQuery` is something you constantly keep a watch on query, whenever that query will be refetched or the data related to that query is changed from anywhere else, this method will keep on emitting the updated data.

It's really simple, you can read the docs [here](https://apollo-angular.com/docs/data/queries/).

Comment: What is the difference between `watchQuery` and subscriptions?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg good question since this is causing a lot of confusion. `watchQuery` will continue to emit results, as long as this data changes in Apollo's cache memory store. Subscriptions will emit results based on changes/events from the server side.

Comment: Broken link now